# Est-ce que c'est correct de remplacer les expressions comme "de moi", "de lui", "de toi" et "de nous" avec leurs pronoms indirects équivalents ?

Tags: grammaire, choix-de-mot, pronoms, en, de

Je me demande s'il est possible d'écrire **me** au lieu de **de moi** ou **te** au lieu de **de toi** ou une substitution équivalente quel que soit le contexte.

Comment: Si on faisait ça, comment est-ce qu'on pourrait distinguer "je parle de lui" et "je parle à lui"?

Comment: @PeterShor _Je parle à lui_ ne se dit pas :-) _Je *lui* parle_ est correct. Juste au cas où...

Comment: Mais on peut dire _c'est à lui que je parle_, différemment de _je lui parle_... Ouais, _il n'y en aura pas de facile_.

Comment: @Frank "Ne se dit pas" est exagéré. C'est du français relâché qui serait probablement compté comme incorrect dans un devoir de français mais on l'entend et le lit même parfois. La tournure est courante dans *Je parle à lui, pas à elle*.

Comment: @Frank Essentiellement vrai. Ce n'est même pas vraiment acceptable dans  une phrase corrective. (ex. : — Non, je ne parle pas à Jean, je parle à lui,) En fait, dans ce cas la forme vraiment idiomatique reste « Non, je ne parle pas à Jean,  c'est à lui que je  parle. »

Comment: @jlliagre _Je parle à lui_ s'utilise? He be ;-) Ah!, dans _Je parle à lui, pas à elle_, oui. Mais tout seul, c'est vraiment bancal...

Comment: @jlliagre Je discerne une petite nuance d'emphase dans _je parle à lui_. Je vois mieux cette tournure dans un contexte où l'on s'addresserait à une troisième personne, pour bien montrer qu'on parle à quelqu'un d'autre. Mais dans un cadre narrative simple, je ne dirais pas _je parle à lui_, mais plutôt _je lui parle_. Est-ce que vous avez le même ressenti?

Comment: Oui bien sûr, mon commentaire n'était pas là pour recommander la tournure à des apprenants mais simplement pour indiquer que l'expression, bien que fustigée par les prescriptivistes, pouvait très bien être rencontrée à l'oral, en particulier quand l'emphase sur *lui* est souhaitée. Je l'ai même trouvée dans la littérature pour les besoins d'une rime. PS: [On se dit tu.](https://french.meta.stackexchange.com/a/158/1109)

Answer (score 1):

Oui, mais il faut préciser ce que c'est ce « *quel que soit le contexte*. »

Normalement le pronom remplace le nom comme complément objet indirect (ou pronom indirect) dans les phrases suivantes qui répondent à la question À qui *****N***** parle ?  *****N***** parle à qui ?

- Je lui parle (je parle à Marc)
- Tu leur parles (tu parles à Jules et Jim)
- Il lui parle (Luc parle à Fatima)
- Elle me parle (Laure parle à moi)

Pour mettre de l'emphase, pour répondre à la question Tu parles à qui, À qui tu parles ? Il parle à qui ? À qui il parle ? (Ou bien sûr à qui parles-tu, à qui parle-t-il ?)

- À lui, je parle à Marc (pas à Luc)
- Tu parles aux enfants ou aux parents ?  À eux, oui je leur parle, je parle
  aux parents (pas aux enfants)
- À moi ?  Elle me parle à moi?  (Elle ne me parlait plus.)

Le pronom *en* peut remplacer *de quelque chose* mais pas *de quelqu'un*.  Ça peut répondre à la question *de qui tu parles* ou *de quoi* ?

- Je parle de moi. (pas de vous)
- Pourquoi tu parles de lui ? (de John, pas de Jean)

Des choses

- Elle en parle beaucoup (de son livre préféré)
- Ils en parlent tout le temps (des nouvelles)

Answer (score 0):

Ce n'est pas possible, à moins de changer le verbe, ce qui ne peut se faire que dans de rares cas, c'est à dire lorsqu'existe un verbe qui signifie la même chose mais se construit sans préposition.

- Il se moque de toi.
- Il te moque. (*emploi littéraire seulement*)

Comment: Merci pour la reponse. La phrase **"Je ne sais pas ce que vous me voulez."** il s'agit de quoi alors? On n'a pas remplace **de moi** avec **me**?

Comment: @YohannesTimket On peut dire "je ne sais pas ce que voulez de moi" ou "je ne sais pas ce que vous me voulez". Dans certains contextes l'un serait mieux que l'autre pour apporter une nuance mais les deux sont corrects.

Comment: @YohannesTimket [TLFi](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/vouloir) : **Qqn veut qqc. de qqn.**_ Attendre ou accepter quelque chose de la part de quelqu'un.. La seconde forme ne se trouve pas dans le TLFi (passer en revue le contenu de la réf. ci-dessus), ni dans le dictionnaire de l'[Académie](https://www.dictionnaire-academie.fr/article/A8V0798) et c'est, comme souvent lorsqu'il s'agit de « vouloir », un idiotisme. Question assez compliquée.  À mon avis elle signifie « quel est l'affaire qui occupe quelqu'un en ce qui concerne une personne » ; il faut faire très attention à ne pas croire 1/2)

Comment: @YohannesTimket que cette famille  de questions a pour réponse « je/tu/il…lui/leur/nous veux/veux/veut/… qqc », ni la famille de formes idiomatiques « je/tu/il… lui/leur/nous/vous… du bien/du mal » (encore des idiotismes) , non, ce n'est pas du tout ça. L'idiotisme auquel vous référez n'existe que sous forme de question. Il s'ensuit que les deux expressions que vous considérez ne sont pas associées à un même sens verbal, et il n'est donc pas question d'une simple substitution. (2/2)

Comment: @None Ceci est le meme pour toutes les phrases faconner ainsi?

Comment: @YohannesTimket Non, toutes les phrases ne fonctionnent pas ainsi. Personnellement je  pense que la plupart du temps il vaut mieux ne pas essayer de trouver des généralités dans le fonctionnement de la langue mais qu'il est préférable de travailler au cas par cas, tout d'abord parce que quand il s'agit de structures de phrases on travaille aussi sur le sens et que le contexte joue un rôle, et par ailleurs le français est une langue assez irrégulière.

Comment: @LPH Merci pour la reponse detaille.